# Is there a way to get ReadyBoost working with 2008 Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, readyboost

I have Windows 2008 Server set up as a workstation, and found that Readyboost made a noticeable improvement in my old Vista box, so I have been wondering if there is a way that ReadyBoost can be used with Windows 2008 Server?

*Edit* Lets pretend I have plenty of RAM , but I also have a large pagefile.sys which I presume means the OS perf still is bound to HD performance

Answer (score 13):

In all honesty, now that you can get 8 GB of memory for $100 or $150, the attraction of ReadyBoost -- using slow USB flash drives as de-facto system pagefile memory cache -- is pretty limited.

Just buy lots of memory! Seriously! :)

Comment: So what's up w/ the pagefile.sys?  Lets pretend I have plenty of RAM , but I also have a large pagefile.sys which I presume means the OS perf still is bound to HD performance....

Comment: @torial: Precache? I'm sure Windows Server 2008 can handle the swappiness correctly. Relevant link: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000422.html

Comment: @alphabeat - I turned off the pagefile.

Comment: But ... I can add a usb drive to my work laptop much easier than I can add ram

Comment: If you're going to run server software, spec out a server capable piece of equipment to do it. There's a reason that desktop OS kludges are not included in server OS packages.

Answer (score 1):

There's a solution [here](http://www.win2008workstation.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=2114#p2114), unfortuantly it doesn't appear to be fully built into the OS as this uses 3rd party software.

Edit: Urg, you need to register on the forum unfortuantly.  Haven't used this myself and can no way guarantee it works.